# How to access the iOS user defaults in React Native?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to access my iOS UserDefaults in my React Native app.
I tried this with [Settings](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/settings) from react-native.

I set the user defaults like this (native in Swift)

```
userDefaults?.set("test", forKey: "test")
```

and also tried it like this

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("test", forKey: "test")
```

And I'm trying to log it like this in my react-native app

```
import {Settings} from 'react-native';

const test = Settings.get('test'); 
console.log(test);
```

This logs `undefined`

I can't find a proper example anywhere, so I hope someone can help me out here.
I need to use the watchKeys() method for the purpose of my app, so react-native-user-defaults is not a solution in my case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you look at the repo for `react-native-user-defaults  you can see clearly the documentation on how to use it https://github.com/wwayne/react-native-user-defaults#get-information-of-a-key

Comment: I used it like that and still get the same error ```Cannot read property 'getObject' of undefined```

Comment: I would create a native method to get UserDefaults values. And expose it to to my react-native application using RCTBridge

Comment: @Hurobaki how can I add a listener so the react-native application is notified when the UserDefaults are updated?

Comment: It’s your React native which will set UserDefaults value ?

Comment: @Hurobaki I want to be able when I click on a refresh button in my widget, to execute some code in my react native app so I need to be able in some way to 'listen' in my react native app when that happens, and it needs to work as well when the host app is killed